# Implement transaction block in web service

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services, wcf

Our company needs to write a web service which will use to submit data from remote site to HQ Servers. This web service will update more then 10 tables from both site(Remote and HQ).

We use SQL Server 2008 in both sides and one batch, will insert data into HQ Server and at the same time need to do some updates on the remote side as well.

The remote site will call the web service on HQ with required data.

Simply I need to commit or roll-back both servers when the web method executed.

What is the best way to handle the transaction block in this situation?